# How to avoid The maximum number of rows permitted on a worksheet been exceeded Exception in jxl

Tags: java, exception, jxl

i'm developing an app in java and i'm using `JXL` library.
So i tried this:

```
File f = new File("test.xls");
ArrayList<String[]> ins = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
           ins.add(new String[]{"-------"+i+"-------", "-------"+i+"-------", "-------"+i+"-------", i,"-------"+i+"-------", "-------"+i+"-------", "-------"+i+"-------","-------"+i+"-------", "-------"+i+"-------", "-------"+i+"-------", "-------"+i+"-------", "-------"+i+"-------", "-------"+i+"-------", "-------"+i+"-------"}); // JUST FOR EXAMPLE
        }
        WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(f);

            WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("TEST1", 0);
            String[] headers = new String[]{"HEADER1", "HEADER2", "HEADER3", "HEADER4", "HEADER5", "HEADER6", "HEADER7", "HEADER8", "HEADER9", "HEADER10", "HEADER12"};
            for(int i=0;i<headers.length;i++){
               sheet.addCell(new Label(i, 0, headers[i]));
            }
            for(int i=0;i<ins.size();i++){
               String tmp[] = ins.get(i);
               for(int j=0;j<tmp.length;i++){
                  sheet.addCell(new Label(j,i+1,tmp[j].toString()));
               }
            }
            workbook.write();
            workbook.close();
    }
```

When i launch it i retrieve:

```
Exception in thread "main" jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException: The maximum number of rows permitted on a worksheet been exceeded
    at jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl.getRowRecord(WritableSheetImpl.java:1214)
    at jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl.addCell(WritableSheetImpl.java:1151)
    at Pr1.main(Pr1.java:52)
Java Result: 1
```

How can i solve it? it is possible that i can't add 21 rows? it's very strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using [Apache POI library](http://poi.apache.org/download.html). It's better to use.

Answer (score 3):

I'm starting with JXL library and looking for some solution to this type of error, which you indicate in your post header, I take to give a solution to your problem in 21 rows.

You have the following code:

```
            for (int j = 0; j <tmp.length; i++) {
               sheet.addCell (new Label (j, i +1, tmp [j].toString ()));
            }
```

Which should be:

```
            for (int j = 0; j <tmp.length; j++) {
               sheet.addCell (new Label (j, i +1, tmp [j].toString ()));
            }
```

What is the difference? Well, you're increase the i instead of j, so the second cycle never ends.

I hope I have helped solve your problem.

Good luck.